# What does the arrow mean in JS file in Visual studio editor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Have seen this in one of the dev machines in a tech forum.

They have the arrows being used instead of tabspaces in JS file.

Attached a screenshot of the same.

What is this btw ?

Picture: [image]

I guess they are using this in order to maintain code readability and alignment.

Comment: They're a visualisation of tabulation characters (‘tabs’), which are otherwise invisible. Aligning code with whitespace like that is called ‘indentation’ and is indeed for readability.

Comment: Yup, but when I try to leave a `tab` space, the `blue arrow` doesn't appear. Instead, I am being shown `...` instead of a `->`

Comment: *How* they are visualised is up to the editor. Most editors let you configure this.

Comment: Cool.. But, any ideas why it doesn't appear when I try to give a `tabspace` ? Whenever I give a `tabspace` it is shown as `...` . What I am missing here ?

Comment: As I said, different editors with different settings will show different things. It being arrows and the arrows being blue is by no means universal. The underlying characters (tabs in this case) will be the same, however, so it doesn't make any difference except for appearances. Simply look through the settings of your editor until you find the right settings and change them to whatever you want (provided your editor lets you do that).

Comment: …another possibility is that you editor is set up to use spaces instead of tabs (a wise choice if you ask me, but that's a whole other debate), so that when you press the tab key the editor inserts spaces instead. This too can of course be configured.

Answer (score 1):

As I am not allowed to post another comment,
here is my answer.
most editors allow the user to choose how to indent the code. 
Using tabs as indentation was most common in earlier days. But then you have the problem that some editors take 1 tab equal to 2 spaces, other editors take them equal to 4 spaces or even more. So the editor allows you to configure that when you press the tab key, it does not insert a tab character (the arrow) but instead it inserts 4 spaces. So in every other editor that is not capable of displaying the tabs or converting tabs to spaces the code is indented correctly.

Most of the time i work without the visualisation of tabs and spaces and carriage line feed at the end of the line, but when it comes to format the code or understand the different blocks, i usually switch visualisation on.